# How to show HTML file in Xcode when there are two files of same file name?

Tags: html, xcode

I have two files that is saved in two separate folders "manmohan" and "sahib". Both have a same file name "1" but different text inside. I want to make sure that when button "manmohan" is clicked it shows the "1" file from "manmohan" folder and when button "sahib" is clicked it shows from "sahib" folder. Below is my code, I am not sure how to set up a path. I can't change the file name as there are over 1000 files that have the same name but different text inside (this would take really long). I am sure there is an easier way out of this.

```
number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
 page.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ang 1"];
 NSString *pages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
 NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pages ofType:@"html"];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```